# Confusion related to calculation of partial derivative

Tags: gradient-descent

I have this function $P = f(\alpha)$. $\alpha$ is a function $\alpha = f(\theta, x)=\theta x$. Now I have

$P = \alpha(x_1+x_2 + ...x_n)$

Now I need to calculate the partial derivative of P wrt $\theta$. Then

$\frac{\partial P}{\partial \theta} = \frac{\partial P}{\partial \alpha} * \frac{\partial \alpha}{\partial \theta} = (x_1+x_2+x_3)*\frac{\partial \alpha}{\partial \theta}$

Now what I am trying to do is use gradient descent to maximize P wrt $\theta$. So what I was expecting was the partial derivative wrt $\theta$ to be a single value. However, Here $\frac{\partial \alpha}{\partial \theta} = \frac{\partial \theta x}{\partial \theta}$ changes wrt to x. So I am a bit confused how to get a single value out of it?

Answer (score 1):

(Chain rule for differentiation:) You should post the function $\alpha()$.

If it were $(x_1+x_2 + ...x_n)^2$ , and $\theta$ were a $\beta$ coefficient in a regression, then $\frac{\partial \alpha}{\partial \theta}$ would be equal to that coefficient. The full derivative would be $2*\beta*(x_1+x_2 + ...x_n)$. The 2 term comes from differentiating $\alpha()$ w.r.t. $(x_1+x_2 + ...x_n)$